# React native Rest API call in background process when app in foreground

Tags: react-native

In React native., How to call REST API on background process when move from one screen to another and also get individual  reference of called API when back to that screen to showcase the status of sync API and it will work when application in foreground.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by background process (do you asynchronous), getting the individual reference, and status of sync API?

Comment: How to perform task in background with react native component and get old reference when I back to that component 


I have one screen on that I am showcase list of offline data need to be sync. Now pressing sync button REST API call will start. Now I want to make that process which is not effect my ongoing task. When I come back to that screen I will check the actual progress or synced api list means get the old refresh of that component which I left and move to another component.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use state management like redux to access data from anywhere in your app
and take a look to this liperares

[react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch)

[react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task)